# List of subfolders with 2 ghost entries how can I avoid them?

Tags: list, batch-file, directory

With a bat file I sorted the subfolders list in a Directory but what are the 2 folders named "." 1 dot and ".." 2 dots ?  actually they are not present in windows explorer and most of all how I can avoid to show them in the list ?

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
> ".\Utils\Check last modified Profile.txt" (
    for /F "delims=" %%D in ('
    dir %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\  /A /all-D /TW /A:D /O:-DE 
') do (
    rem print each item:        
       echo %%~D %
      )
)
endlocal
```

image here > https://i.stack.imgur.com/i79Bk.jpg

Comment: Add the `/B` option to the `dir` command line, so there are no header and footer lines, and no items `.` and `..` returned…

Comment: Perhaps you want something like this command line: `pushd "%APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" && ((for /F "eol=| delims=" %%I in ('dir /AD-L /B /O-D /TW 2^>nul') do echo %%~tI %%I)>"%~dp0Utils\Check last modified Profile.txt" & popd)`

Comment: THANKS TO ALL !! now I know that the ghost folders are not real folders and are not specific to a single Directory so I can delete them from the list using a .vbs script and create an updated text file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dir %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\  /A /all-D /TW /A:D /O:-DE ^|findstr /v /e /L /c:"."
```

worked for me.

The `dir` output is sent to `findstr` which allows through lines which do not (/v) end (/e) with the literal (/L) string "."

Directories cannot be created that end with `.`

I believe I do not need to comment further on the attributes-selection specification.

The `^` is required to have the pipe applied to the `dir` command, not the `for`.

I'll make no further comment on the attributes-selection specified.

Comment: THANKS !! now I know that the ghost folders are not real folders and are not specific to a single Directory so I can delete them from the list using a .vbs script and create an updated text file, Well in the end I decided to delete also the lines with "volume" and "bytes" in them

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the current directory. `..` is it's parent directory.

Explorer hides them.

```
Dir C:\windows\.\.\..
```

Comment: OK probably they are only needed when using relative paths therefore not in windows explorer thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1):

I have decided to post this because the existing answers appear to be using the same crazy and incorrect options for the `Dir` command. The following examples use the appropriate `findstr.exe` method of eliminating the `.` and `..` directory entries from your listing, sorted according to most recently modified to least recent. I have included the full path to `findstr.exe` to eliminate the possibility of `%PATH%` and/or `%PATHEXT%` modifications from not being able to locate it.

If you wanted the same output format, then this should work for you:

```batch-file
@For /F "Tokens=1*Delims=:" %%G In ('"Dir "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" /AD/O-DE 2>NUL|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ELNV ".""')Do @Echo(%%H
```

If you don't need the empty lines then, this should omit those for you:

```batch-file
@For /F "Delims=" %%G In ('"Dir "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" /AD/O-DE 2>NUL|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ELV ".""')Do @Echo %%G
```

And if you only needed the directory name lines, then perhaps this will satisfy you:

```batch-file
@For /F EOL^=^ Delims^= %%G In ('"Dir "%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles" /AD/O-DE 2>NUL|%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /ELV ".""')Do @Echo %%G
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use and add this switch `/B`

```
@echo off
@for /F "delims=" %%D in ('
    dir %APPDATA%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\ /A /all-D /TW /A:D /O:-DE /B
') do (
    echo %%~D
    )
```

Comment: thanks for the feedback but using the /B switch I'm going to lose the last modified dates and I really would like to keep them